# Hardware Diagnostic Windows10 (System crashes / Black screen)

Tags: windows-10, freeze, hardware-failure, diagnostic

I very often have freezes of my Windows10 Computer, especially under heavy load (mostly in games).

Symptoms: Black screen and sound repeating infintely. No more reaction on any key. Otherwise my PC from 2016 performans just great.

How often : Between 0 and 10 times a day. Did not find any logic in the regularity, sometimes it just goes round for hours.

Workaround: I have to fully restart my PC (forced shutdown)

What I did try already:

(1) Windows10 Events: I see "Critical errors" that Windows was restarted without normal shutdown, but no information on what could have caused the problem.

(2) AIDA64 - System stability tests: Sometimes crashes after about one hour, but often goes without errors for hours. Measured temperature always stays beneth 100 degrees Celsius.

(3) CyrstalDiskInfo tells me all my hard-drives are "good"

(4) All Intel and AMD drivers are up to date, the same for any optional Windows update

(5) PC-Doctor tells me my sytem is in a critical state, because of the unexpected shutdowns, but no info about any reason for system hang-up.

(6) PC-Doctor diagnostic scans (stress tests) all tell me everything should be fine

I suppose there could be an error on the CPU / GPU / Motherboard, but I don't really know.

Hardware details:
"Ankermann-PC - NEW Big KING, Intel Core i7-6700K 4x4.00GHz Skylake, Sapphire Radeon R9 390 Nitro 8GB, RAM 16GB DDR4-2133, Samsung SSD 850 PRO 256GB"

Comment: Is there a PC Manufacturer Hardware test app?  Run that.  Also run the Manufacturer's Driver Update app and update all drivers including BIOS.

Comment: It was an no-name PC by Ankerman, I add details in the description.

Comment: What you describe indicates the problem is likely connected to your GPU.  The kernel is likely encountering a problem that it cannot recover from since you indicate, the problem happens primarily with resource-intensive tasks. The fact AIDA64 crashes could also indicate it's time to kill the dust bunnies in your case, but that isn't guaranteed to be the problem.  WIthout more specific information is tough to even suggest that might be the case.

Comment: Thx, yes changing GPU would be less expensive then exchanging entire PC ;)

Comment: execute real ram test overnight, if there's integrated gpu try removing card for some time but better would be if you can get known good gpu to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I begin to believe the sole debugging tools which exists are tools like listed above. Even so none of them pointed me 100% to a direction.

Finally after months of (i)regular crashes my graphic card died, I replaced it and my initial problem was resolved.

I am still listening for better diagnostic tools :)